# Can I change Vcc to some other pin?

Tags: arduino-uno, pins, voltage-level, hardware, input

I was working on an Arduino Uno and while carrying it to my teacher the wire's pin got stuck into the Vcc of 5 V. Can I set Vcc to other inputs? If so, then how?

Comment: if you are an english speaking person, then your grammar needs some serious work. looks like you wrote three sentences, but there is no proper punctuation. as a result it is absolutely unclear what you are asking. .... what is a `wire's pin` ?

Comment: No, you can't program it to any other pin, but you can pull out the wire by simply sticking another wire in, putting a tiny amount of solder on that new wire and then the solder would stick to that stuck wire too. Afterwards, you can pull the new wire out, and both wires will come out as one. Happened to me once and this way I got it out.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. Well, you can if all you want is a few mA (just set a pin to OUTPUT and HIGH), but chances are you need more than that. So no.

Answer (score 0):

The VCC pin is not programmable.

However, both ICSP buses have a pin that connects to the 5V VCC line. See the diagram here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKz2l.png
 These are both male headers while the pin marked 5V is a female header so you will need to use a different connector than what you used previously.

If you choose to go this route, you should use the bottom ICSP header (opposite side of the board from the USB) as it is wired directly to the ATEMEGA328 chip. For this same reason, you should be very careful if you are trying to apply or draw power from any of the 5V pins as they are not protected by a fuse.